# How to make an OS CPU/Process Scheduler

Tags: c++

**Here is my assignment:** In this subproject you are charged to design and implement a Ready Queue (RQ) to support a Scheduler subsystem of an OS. The RQ must be designed as a ‘priority’ queue, which is governed by the FIFO policy. Write a Scheduler class to manage this queue – scheduling processes from the queue. Assume that the queue length is unknown from the start when the computer system is booted, or turned on. Processes get enqueued and dequeued depending on their assigned priority numbers, which are randomly generated.  The priority order of the queue is always preserved. The processes are executed on a virtual CPU (object) for a random-execution time when dequeued by the Scheduler from the RQ. Write a CPU class that has one member function, ‘Execute,’ which simply gets called to execute the process. Write a Process class that generates ‘processes’ at random time intervals, and calls the Scheduler object to enqueue the processes. The entire logic of this virtual CPU’s ‘Execute’ function is to simply set a time-counter for each process with the random-execution time when it is dequeued/called by the Scheduler object. Balance the number of processes-generated and processes-executed using the Poisson/exponential distribution functions (as you generate the random numbers). The times to generate process arrivals and scheduling are mutual exclusive, and random.

Test the ‘simulator’ for 1000 runs.

Essentially I need to make a linked list (the ready queue) and 3 classes...1 class Scheduler which will add "processes" to the RQ, 2 class CPU that will "execute" the process on the rq and finally 3rd class called Processor that creates the "processes"

I'm lost in the fact, that I'm not sure what the "processes" I'm supposed create are, and how the classes will interact with each other.
Any help would be apprieciated.

Comment: Sounds like a conversation you should have with your instructor.

Comment: priority queue and FIFO policy are quite contradicting each other

Comment: I recommend you research a good Operating Systems reference / book.  Maybe take a class in it. ;-)

Comment: The MicroCOS site has some source code you could download and study.